# InvalidArgumentException Please provide a valid cache path Error laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I'm working with `Laravel 5.2` and i have an error when i run `composer update` or `artisan optimize` ..

i've searched on my vendor, i didn't found compiled.php file ! i try to generate this i run the artisan optimize, i have the same error

```
[InvalidArgumentException]          
  Please provide a valid cache path

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1
```

how i can resolve this ?

Comment: `php artisan cache:clear` try this

Comment: I got the same error [InvalidArgumentException] Please provide a valid cache path

Comment: please post your full error message in question

Comment: you gave permissions to storage foder?

Comment: You should have storage folder

Comment: I didn't have storage folder !

Comment: You should have it

Comment: How did you install Laravel?

Comment: it works now .. i added storage folder ... thank you friend

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please Try it:

create these folders under **storage/framework**:

- sessions
- views
- cache

And also you can use this command to install:

```
sudo composer install
```

Its will be working.

Comment: i didn't have storage folder, i create it ?

Comment: see your root off-course has storage folder it's laravel package flow another laravel project.

Comment: I removed the views folder and I created it again. I got error after that... This solution worked for me, thanks dude.