# Bootstrap/cache folder missing in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I clone a project from Git and hit `composer install` then I hit any command it shows an error and there is no Bootstrap/cache folder.

> [ErrorException]
>     file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\iorwms\bootstrap/cache/services.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: maybe just a composer update instead of a composer install ??

Comment: Give permissions to bootstrap folder after downloading laravel project!

Comment: i am using windows. so there has no problem with permission @HirenGohel..

Comment: composer install or composer update can't solve this issue.. i already try those.. i solve this issue.. just i copy this folder from laravel 5.2 master file...@kevinniel

Comment: @Md.MerazHossain You mean you copied bootstrap folder from another project?

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44177140/invalidargumentexception-please-provide-a-valid-cache-path-error-laravel-5-2 It works for me.

Comment: @HirenGohel i copy just cache folder

Comment: Ok, anyway you fixed it now!

Comment: Yes.. thanks for your response @HirenGohel

Comment: Basically, i think you don't need to copy it as it created default in laravel. We clear the cache using `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 show ErrorException file\_put\_contents failed to open stream: No such file or directory (OS Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959985/laravel-5-show-errorexception-file-put-contents-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-f)